# How do I animate NSView with curve

Tags: macos, nsanimationcontext, nsanimation

I know how to animate `NSView` objects using `+[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:completionHandler:]`, but I can't see a way of setting the animation curve on this type of animation. I see that `NSAnimation` has an init method which includes a `NSAnimationCurve` parameter, but I cannot figure out how to specify what should actually happen during the animation using this method. The documentation for `NSAnimation` is really difficult to understand and I can't find any examples. So if somebody could explain how I can either add a curve to `NSAnimationContext` animations or specify the animations in a `NSAnimation` animation, that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re looking for is [`timingFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsanimationcontext/1524985-timingfunction).

You can set it inside of the `runAnimationGroup` block:

```
NSAnimationContext.currentContext.timingFunction = …
```

and either use [predefined functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatimingfunction/predefined_timing_functions) or create your own with control points.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I did see the `timingFunction` property but for some reason it didn't register as what I needed. The docs for NSView animation are a mess and make it sounds much more complicated than it really is.

Comment: To complete the snippet you provided, I had to import QuartzCore and then do `context.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];`

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of [pointium's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54607214/3151675):

```
NSAnimationContext.current.timingFunction = .init(name: .linear)
```